# How do i interpret this Scatter Plot

Tags: data-visualization, interpretation, scatterplot

I'm researching on the relationship between Scholarship and years. I have scatter plot below. The x axis is equal to the total amount of scholarship for a student. The y axis show the term a student took to complete his/her phD.

[image]

I'm not sure how I should interpret this scatter plot. I would be appreciate for any help.

==== editted 2021/08/11===

I changed the transparency of the scatterplot so I can check the density of bottom-left area. The result is like below.

[image]

Comment: For future readers: this figure is hard to read despite the added transparency. A hexbin plot would be a better way to visualise this. Axis labels are always useful too.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because there's insufficient information available to interpret this, partly because the plots are themselves not clear, and also because the two plots differ from each other in the data shown despite being described as differing only in transparency.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that the average student, will take on average a 1.5 Scholarships (somewhere between 0-2.5) if finish on average the Ph.D. in 5.5 terms (somewhere between 0-10), i.e. if we could average the points in the left bottom corner.

Also, for sure we can identify that students that need a big amount of terms to finish their Ph.D. for sure they have the least amount of scholarships, whereas the most scholarships are taken by students that are relatively quick in finishing their Ph.D. 0-10 terms.

Answer (score 1):

At first glance, I'd say that, with inceasing X, Y stabilizes at around 5.

At second glance: can you make points transparent to see how dense they are in bottom left area of your plot?

Comment: Thank you for your help. I made the scatter plot dots transparent so I can check the density. It seems most of samples are located in the bottom left area. The problem is I have no idea how to interpret this...

Comment: @JayLIm Points on transparent plot are very different from those on non-transparent one. Why is that?